# How would the customer edit the website you've sold to him?

Tags: web-development, customer-relations

I am pretty sure that in one month, I can create a website semi to professional with really good design, functionality and security. I have made quite a few researches and I have found websites where I can advertise my own website and sell it.
However, I still have some hesitation:

### What risk do I take selling a website?

Related to the first question, I've got a second question:

### How would the customer edit the website you've sold to him?

As I sold a website and not a CMS, the customer will have to edit the code if he want to do some updates. How could I make it easy for him to add the content he wants to the website?

Comment: If the customer doesn't know the low level things needed for modifying the site, and you're not providing an easy to use interface (which is what wordpress etc. offer), then the customer won't edit the website. Simple as that. Also asking "should I even sell it" from us is odd. We only know that you've claimed it's the best thing since sliced bread. If it's true, then it should be selling like hotcakes, and I don't see why you wouldn't sell it.

Comment: Talking about yourself is not very relevent for the question,or at least can be much shorter. Go straight to the point

Comment: @Keptox I do know that, but I also know a lot of people who will just underestimate me only because of my age, as some have done before...that's why I wanted to make it a little big longer...but I think this edit you've done is perfect...thank you for that.

Comment: The risks of selling a site is you won't get paid, or you might get sued if the customer is not happy about what they got from you. For mitigating the risk, you need a contract, and for making the contract right, you need a lawyer (take the time to look this [youtube video, it is exactly about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=jVkLVRt6c1U)). So this makes your first question a legal one, which is unfortunately off-topic for this site.

Comment: As for the second question, if implementing editing tool is too long/expensive/hard, another solution would be to keep in contact with the customer and make small contracts for each upgrade

Comment: Exactly that I didn't know...that's why I am asking...the website I intend to create is either a portofolio or a blog website so even though the customer won't know how to code he will repeat the same process over and over again and I think after a while he will learn how to do it him self, but I wasn't quite sure about it. One small question I did not mention directly in the post is that is it legal for me to sell a website at my age?

Comment: @KnownAsDon that depends a lot about law (and country you live in), so it would be better to ask it on [law.se]. I know that in some cuntries, young actors/singer **can** sign contract and earn money but it's on a specific bank account, that you can use only once you are adult. Another problem would be for customer to have enough trust to sign contract with a 16 yo teen without any diploma or experience

Comment: "As I sold a website and not a CMS" - well, you don't need to "sell a CMS" to use it for website building. I recommend you use a free CMS like Contao, Typo3 or Joomla for building the website, that is what most professionals do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to go here that I'm aware of:

Option #1:

Build CMS functionality into the site, so if a header needs to be updated, provide a control for doing that.

Option #2:

You provide maintenance and do the updates for a fee.